# Formatting String out from Oracle Select Query

Tags: sql, oracle, string, oracle10g

Lets say when I run the following query,

```
SELECT NAME 
  FROM EMP;
```

It return the following 2 rows.

```
NAME
------------
Jan Jones
Arne Barnie
```

But I wanted it in the following format

```
J. Jones
A. Barnie
```

How I can get that?

Comment: What version of Oracle?  Frankly, working on the full name for string manipulation is not recommended -- what if someone has a last name with a space between two words?

Comment: @OMG - its a simple homework so we can assume that each name has 2 words. I am using Oracle Express Edition 10g on win 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be possible with `regexp_replace`:

```
with names as (
  select 'Jan Jones'   name from dual union all
  select 'Arne Barnie' name from dual
)
select
  regexp_replace(name, '(.)[[:alpha:]]* *([[:alpha:]]*)', '\1. \2') name
from
  names;
```

Alternatively, if you prefer the `\X` notation over the `[[:...:]]` notation, you can use

```
regexp_replace(name, '(.)\w* *(\w*)', '\1. \2')
```

Answer (score -1):

There are no short cuts like `DECODE` to do this
[I think this is your best bet.](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_display_multiple_column_values_same_rows.htm)

Comment: that's for string aggregation, which is nothing to do with the OP's question.

Comment: @Jeffrey, as you may notice I answered the question 5 hrs ago and at that time the question was different. Since then the question was edited and I notice the required output format has changed. The original question had two names in a row - thanks!

Comment: ah - my apologies, I didn't think of that. If you edit your answer I'll remove the downvote.